# Why code in OnNewIntent() is executed twice?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-asynctask

I am using `singleTop` mode in my main `Activity`. I am using `SearchWidget`

This is manifest for my `MainAcivity`:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

`onNewIntent`  is called twice:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {


    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {

     // here is my code     

    }

}
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: Are you using the emulator? See the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633282/searchable-activity-being-called-twice

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Hardware keyboard to perform search? If yes, the double-execution is a known but never fixed Android bug.

You might want to try using an integer lock variable to avoid double-execution.

I have an Android 4.2.2 device with the same issue. Similar behavior was observed in Android Emulator.

Comment: really?? the bug was never fixed?